# application deployment fails in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

When I try to Run my war file in netbeans with tomcat server, I get this error.

```
Tomcat server started.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\saeed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\GomrokProject\PoliceSmsCenter\target\PoliceSmsCenter-2.0-SNAPSHOT deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fsaeed%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext6847039033559451727.xml&path=/PoliceSmsCenter<br> http://localhost:8084/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fsaeed%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext6847039033559451727.xml&path=/PoliceSmsCenter"<br> The module has not been deployed.<br> See the server log for details.
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:179)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:131)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:211)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you post the server log?

Comment: What is the reason available in server log?

Comment: it is empty! there isn't any text in it.

Comment: the problem start when I add one jar project to another project. after that, I can't run none of my projects

Comment: Stupid question, but have you tried doing a Clean and Build?

Comment: Can you explain how this problem arose with more detail? You're saying you added the same jar dependency to multiple projects?

Answer (score 0):

Try including following dependency in your pom file. Use `<scope>provided</scope>` to indicate that you need the artifact to compile, but not to have it in your war.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @saeed arash Did you try adding above dependency or you already have it in there?